# Position span inside input - NOT FOR PLACEHOLDER

Tags: css, dynamic, positioning

I'm in the process of developing a project in which my client wants a "show/hide" password feature - simple enough to do, however they want the button inside the input box. Which is also simple to do - if we were working on a static screen.

However, this is a project using media queries, and so the question becomes how to dynamically position the anchor (the anchor is our controlling element for the mask/unmask) *inside* the input.

I'm at a loss. I've set up a simple fiddle showing the ideal goal (not taking into account border-radius, etc) here: http://jsfiddle.net/x4jPE/

**Solution**

http://jsfiddle.net/LyfTJ/2/

*Many thanks to Rob W*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a container, and set the `position` CSS attribute to `relative`, so that any inside absolutely-positioned element is relative to the container. Also add `display:inline-block`, so that the container shrinks to the minimum required size (=the size of the input field).

Then, add a `padding-right:42px` to the password field, so that the button does not overlap the contents of the field. Finally, add `position:absolute; right:0;` to the anchor, so that it's positioned at the right side of the input field.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LyfTJ/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="zpass">
    <input type="password" name="zpass" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".zpass").each(function(){
        $(this).append("<a>Show</a>");
        var zpass = $("input", this)[0];
        $("a", this)[0].href = "javascript:;";
        $("a", this).click(function(){
            if(zpass.type == "password"){
                zpass.type = "text";
                this.innerHTML = "Hide";
            } else {
                zpass.type = "password";
                this.innerHTML = "Show";
            }
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.zpass {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.zpass > input {
    padding: 8px 42px 8px 8px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.zpass > a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 9px 4px 8px;
    font-size: .85em;
    color: #a5a5a5;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33px;
}
.zpass > a:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: While this works, it's not quite what I'm looking for as far as the Javascript goes. This will only work on pre-defined elements by ID; my ideal script will look at all `<a class="toggle-pass">` and on click, change the previous input's type. Is this possible? Tinkered around a bit with your script but unable to successfully modify it.

Comment: Essentially, I want to be able to run `$('.toggle-pass').click(function(){togglePass();});` in the head and have it change the type of the previous input.

Comment: Rob - http://jsfiddle.net/LyfTJ/2/ - that is exactly what I wanted to accomplish. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks